# MarkerLayer on ready not being called for bounds feature

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mapbox

I'm trying to use the bounds feature to fit my pins to the screen. Using the example code on the MapBox website I came up with this.

```
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'username.map-3li14vzt').setView([51.53769, -0.07655], 13);

    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();

    var markerLayer = L.mapbox.markerLayer().setGeoJSON({
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: $scope.geo // this is my json
    }).addTo(map);

    /* fit pins to screen */

    markerLayer.on('ready', function(e) {
        console.log('Maps ready!');
        map.fitBounds(markerLayer.getBounds());
    });
```

The map is being created correctly and pins dropped in the right place. However, the markerLayer ready function isn't being called (can't see "Maps ready!" in console).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're calling `.setGeoJSON()`, the `ready` event won't fire - it's only for asynchronous calls like `.loadURL()`. You can just remove that event binding entirely and say:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'username.map-3li14vzt').setView([51.53769, -0.07655], 13);

map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
map.doubleClickZoom.disable();

var markerLayer = L.mapbox.markerLayer().setGeoJSON({
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: $scope.geo // this is my json
}).addTo(map);

/* fit pins to screen */
console.log('Maps ready!');
map.fitBounds(markerLayer.getBounds());
```

Comment: Hi. Is there any similar event also when using  setGeoJSON()?  Something like 'load-finish'..

Comment: No - there isn't any reason to use an event for setGeoJSON, since it'd just run immediately, exactly the same as if you just wrote the code below the setGeoJSON call.